# Create a custom WinXP with auto-installed applications

Tags: windows-xp, image, ghost

I'm looking for a way to create a custom Windows XP that would contain specific applications.

I get to install lots of WinXP nowadays and instead of fetching all the software all over again I wish make some sort of custom-image of that XP version.

Anyone got any clue which software (or set of softwares) could help me do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could try creating a WindowsXP installed computer with all the applications you need, and then use "sysprep" tool to create an image that can be then put on many computers.

Sysprep allows you to seal an image that will run a "mini-setup" when first booted. This way you can have a single image, to fit many hardware types and with all your software pre-installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, sysprep's what I use to do exactly that.  To expand a little on katriel's answer, I usually:

- Install the OS, OS updates and any
  drivers required, including drivers
  for hardware that may be present in
  other PCs that I apply the image to.
- Install any apps that I need.
- Run a little perl script to write
  zeroes to all the blank bits of the
  disk.  This will make the image
  compress better.
- Run sysprep and put in all the
  options for the mini-setup, then use
  the re-seal function to get the
  machine into the proper first-boot
  state.
- Image the PC - I use G4U, but
  anything else (WDS, Ghost, whatever)
  will do just as well.